# How to recreate the listview of a former ListFragment after pressing back button

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-listfragment, fragmenttransaction

I have a ListFragment with a listview in it, that contains a navigation-structure. By selecting an item of the list, the next navigation hierarchy stage should be displayed. And so on.

The next hierarchy stage is created by a new fragment (remove the old fragment and add the same fragment new via fragmant transactions by using addToBackStack), in which the arrayadapter of the  new listview is updated to the items of the next navigation hierarchy. That work pretty fine.

I want the user to have the possibility to navigate back via the back button. And here start my problems. I have no clue how to save the listview so it could be recreated after using the back button.

I thought using onSaveInstanceState would be a good idea. But onSaveInstanceState ist not called when the transaction gets comitted. I checked it by placing a Log.d("..","...) in the method. It´s not called. (What I found out, is, that onSaveInstanceState is called when rotating from portrait- to landscape-view and vice-versa. But that´s no help for my problem).

So what would be the best idea to store the elements of the listview and get it back to recreate the listview after using the back button and the former fragment is getting created? All items are Strings that are stored in an ArrayList that is bound to the ListAdapter.

---

Here my code. I implemented an interface, via the click on an item in the listview calls a method in the parent-activity. In this method I first call a method to fill the already existing ArrayList (navigationsItems) with the new items that are content of the next navigation-stage:

The code of my ArrayAdapter:

```
arrayAdapterFuerNaviList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        BRC_BoardOverviewActivity.this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                    navigationsItems);
```

In this method I first call a method to fill an ArrayList (navigationsItems) with the items of the next navigation-stage:

```
// load new itemlist to navigation-
public void inhaltAktuelleNaviListeInArrayLaden() {

    navigationsItems.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < prefs.getInt("aktuelleNaviListe_size", 0); i++) {
        (...)
        navigationsItems.add(titel);
    }
}
```

Then I call the method, with which I load the new ListFragment and bind the new ArrayAdapter to it:

```
// push navifragment to BackStack and create a new instance of it
public void naviFragmenteNeuLaden() {

            // get a reference to the actual ListFragment
    Fragment removefragment = frgm.findFragmentById(R.id.navi_container);

    // initialize ne ListFragment
    BRC_NavigationsFragment navifragment = (BRC_NavigationsFragment) frgm
            .findFragmentById(R.id.navi_container);

    // remove the old and bind the new ListFragment from/to the container ...
    FragmentTransaction frgmta = frgm.beginTransaction();
    frgmta.remove(removefragment);
    frgmta.add(R.id.navi_container, navifragment);

    // ... push the old ListFragment on the BackStack and commit ...
    frgmta.addToBackStack(null);
    frgmta.commit();
    frgm.executePendingTransactions();

    // ... bind the updated ArrayAdapter to the new ListFragment ...
    try {
        navifragment.setListAdapter(arrayAdapterFuerNaviList);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // ... and notify 
    try {
        arrayAdapterFuerNaviList.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As mentioned, forward-navigating is no problem. But when i press back button for e.g. in the 2nd navigation-stage, the former ListFragment gets loaded (verfified with Log.d("..."."...)-Messages in onCreatView() of ListFragment), but the former listview which was in it isn´t created.

---

I am currently working on a new approach. When you click on an item in the list, I write the current list, together with a reference to the current ListFragment into a vector based stack. Then I catch with "onBackPressed()"-method the press of the back button. So now when the button is pressed, I call on the already mentioned methods (see above), write the item-data from the stack back into the list, call via the stored reference the forme ListFragmt and bind the updated ArrayAdapter to it. This is work in progress actually. I will write the result of this approach when finished.

Comment: Why not make a `ListFragment` for each of those screens?

Comment: As I mentioned, I create a new ListFragment with a new Listview by navigating forward. Example 

a) Item 1 clicked
b) new ListFragment creation; put old ListFragment to backStack
c) fetching the right items for the next navigation stage
d) bind the new items to new ListFragment
e) Forward navigation done! All works fine till here!

Then the problem:

User is in the next stage (see a) to e) above) and 
f) presses back button.
g) The former ListFragment gets pulled from backStack
h) ListFragment gets created
i) but the former ListView gets not created (empty ListFragment)

Comment: Post the code you use to populate that ListFragment and also how you move to the next fragment.

Comment: I added the code. See above.

Comment: Also I added an explanation of a new approach for solving my problem.

Comment: I think you're complicating things by using the same fragment. Have a look at another approach. https://gist.github.com/luksprog/4731357

Comment: Thanks for the code at github. But with this, there is a new problem for me. The navigtion-hierarchy isn´t fix. It depends on the structure of a discussion-forum (board, forum, sub-forum etc.) and it´s contenst (topics). This structure is get loaded in the parent activity and depends on the user-rights in the discussion-forum (member can see more forums then guests, for example; by this way the navigation-depth varies, too). So i have to create the navigation-structure on the fly. In your approach I must have fix lists for the several navigation-stages, which i don´t have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.

For the different navigation contents of the ListView I have defined a class "Naviliste", in which all the items are stored. If someone clicks on an item, then the a new listview with the correspondingly new list will be generated. These lists are indexed, so each list get´s a fixed ID assigned.

By clicking an item in the ListView, the ID of the current Naviliste is pushed onto a stack. After that a new fragment will be created an the new list bound to it. The same procedure repeats if the user goes a step further, and so on ...

If the user pushes the back button to go a step back, the following is done:

The push of the back button is catched via the onPressedBack()-method placed in the parent activity. Via this method an own method is called. This pulls the last ID that was pushed onto the stack and then builds with it in a new created fragment the former list.

At the same time I will run along a counter that counts in which navigation depth I am. In each navigation step forward it get´s inceased by 1. And in reverse just reduced by 1. With this counter I am able to query if the user is in the navigation-root (counter = 0) and once more pushes the back button to leave the current activity. If so, i call finish() and the parent activity with its fragments get´s closed. Voilá!

It works great. Took a little bit time to get over it. But now I am happy that my solution works. :)